# How to exclude classes from cobertura analysis in sonar report when running from Jenkins/Hudson Plugin?

Tags: java, jenkins, hudson, sonarqube, cobertura

There is some classes I want to exclude from my cobertura coverage analysis:
- com.foo.NiceStuff
- com.foo.CoolStuff

This is the only way I know to exclude them:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.5.2</version>
<configuration>
    <instrumentation>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>com/foo/NiceStuff.class</exclude>
            <exclude>com/foo/CoolStuff.class</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </instrumentation>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

But the sonar analysis is not instanciate by maven but by the sonar Jenkins/Hudson Plugin...
So this configuration is not used.

Do you know any place to configure this exclusion ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Sonar should be using the same configuration unless you're running the analysis there differently than the build you're running in Jenkins. However, you can also tell Sonar to reuse the reports created by Jenkins instead of generating its own, which has the additional benefit of speeding up the Sonar analysis. You just nave to set `sonar.dynamicAnalysis` to `reuseReports` and tell Sonar where to find the test reports. See ["Reusing Existing Reports"](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Code+Coverage+by+Unit+Tests+for+Java+Project#CodeCoveragebyUnitTestsforJavaProject-ReusingExistingReports) on the Sonar wiki for details.

Comment: Not sure to understand you. This doesn't solve my problem, does-it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it will. Look at the console output of your jenkins job, and you'll probably see that jenkins is running the sonar maven plugin to do the analysis, which basically just runs the maven build as configured. If not, then what I said doesn't apply.